# WAMP not running jQuery AJAX successfully

Tags: jquery, ajax, wamp

I've set up a WAMP server to build and test a website. It's my first time and it's going swimmingly until I get to anything involving AJAX (jQuery based).

Basic start is a user login form. Submit button goes to JavaScript function which has an AJAX call within to check the database for user etc etc. This was failing. Google's Dev Tools were saying the issue was "unexpected token <" at line whatever. The line was when the AJAX returned.

Reading up this seems to be an issue when the AJAX is returning a blank html page "" which is not valid JavaScript and thus throws this error. And in this context I'm guessing it would throw this if say a 404 page was being throw up if the php could not be found.

So I crawled over that for an hour with no joy. Then I mocked up a simple version of the AJAX and ran that hoping to build the user login form again step by step to find my issue. That didn't work.

On a hunch I build the exact same thing on a real server and found that it did indeed work. So now I'm guessing that my issue has something to do with a WAMP server setup. I was led to believe that AJAX calls would just work from setup.

Any ideas of what might be causing this and where to go to look for info on how to setup WAMP correctly for jQuery and AJAX?

More obscure attempts involved swapping out:

```
http://localhost/ 
for 
http://127.0.0.1/
```

which threw a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error. I thought great Apache is on a different port. Nope Apache is on port 80.

Attempted to add in:

```
crossDomain: true;
dataType: "jsonp",
```

to the AJAX call and returned a: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html" but this returned to the "unexpected token <" error.

I'm running out of ideas, so if you have any I'd be appreciative.

edit - I thought I'd throw in my basic case which is failing at line ten of the test1.js file:

test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test1.js"></script>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="test_form" name="test_form">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="email" id="test_email" name="test_email" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

test1.js

```
$(function () {
    $("#test_form").submit(function() {
        var postData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",               
            data: postData,
            url: "http://localhost/test/test1.php",
            success: function(data) {           
                var test_data = JSON.parse(data);
                if (test_data.test_success == "success") {
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost/test/test2.html");                    
                } else {    
                    window.alert("Test Failed.", function(){}, "Test Failed", "OK");        
                }
            }               
        });         
        return false;   
    });
});
```

test1.php

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["test_email"];
if ($email == 'test@test.com') {
    $arr = array("test_success" => "success");
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    $arr = array("test_success" => "failed");
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>          
    </head>
    <body>
        Success!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your ajax, I don't see 'dataType : 'json'` anywhere

Comment: I've tried with and without, however in these instances without is causing ajax() to fail silently. Presumably because what is being returned is not json, but html.

Comment: What does your network panel inspector show when you see the ajax request?  You should be able to see the headers, request, response to the javascript code.  And what happens when you do `console.log(test_data);`?

Comment: I just tested your code on my XAMPP server, and it runs fine! It redirects to the test2.html page with the text : `Success!`... Maybe there's some error with your wamp setup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for helping. The fault was all mine (as expected). In the more complicated version of my code it wasn't working because some failed PHP code was being nice and returning a webpage that lays out the errors. Unfortunately for me I was not handling this exception very well (at all) and as I was expecting to receive JSON not HTML all hell broke loose.

I compounded my mistake when I went to make the code smaller to track down the specific cause of the error, I was leaving in remnants of the larger code (specifically the real_escape_string() function which was nowhere to be found causing the failure when I ran it as a test case. Once I took that out I worked back and put in better error handling and voile I can see the failures and fix them like I knew what I was doing.